# Android pushes off LinearLayout - android development?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-emulator

I am a beginner and I am working on a simple app. I have 2 pictures on the top of the screen, and one LinearLayout in the bottom all of them are assigned by "android:layout_marginTop...".
The problem is, I have tried that on my sony xperia x8(320 x 480 pixels, 3.0 inches ) and the mainmenu which has 3 images(buttons) are being pushed off the screen, please help. And it does not work on the android emulator I can't open it in the emulator but I can on my phone. it says: "This.....app has stopped unexpectedly"

This is how I want it to look like:

https://docs.google.com/a/seoulforeign.com/file/d/0Byv_19fXkk1MaGtZR3Y3Z1lsNk0/edit

This is how it looks on my sony x8 screen

https://docs.google.com/a/seoulforeign.com/file/d/0Byv_19fXkk1MaE5RazNGdVF2eHM/edit

MinSDK :2.1 
Target : 4.2

Here is my main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/mainbg"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/headingmain" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="-83dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-12dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/headingby" />

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_weight="-30"
  android:id="@+id/MainMenu"
  android:layout_width="200dp"
  android:layout_height="200dp"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_marginTop="275dp"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

 <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
      android:layout_width="180dp"
      android:layout_height="55dp"
      android:background="@drawable/playbutton"
      android:padding="0dp"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:src="@drawable/playbutton" />

 <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
      android:layout_width="180dp"
      android:layout_height="55dp"
      android:background="@drawable/helpbutton"
      android:padding="0dp"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:src="@drawable/helpbutton" />

  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
      android:layout_width="180dp"
      android:layout_height="55dp"
      android:background="@drawable/aboutbutton"
      android:padding="0dp"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:src="@drawable/aboutbutton" />

    <!--  end of main menu! -->
    </LinearLayout>  


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your log cat details also

Comment: post your log details what exception u r getting

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Byv_19fXkk1MeUNUN2FvSDNXMXM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: why your are using the values in minus(-)

Comment: can u post the images so that i can create a exact layout for u

Comment: Sure, give me 1 minute!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Byv_19fXkk1McXdUTWV2NjRQTlk&usp=sharing   

For the images!! Thank YOU!!! SO MUCH!!

Comment: Should I export my entire android project?

Comment: or just the workspace folder of this project ?

Comment: okay, but in what format you want me to send it? as a folder of my workspace?

Comment: the one thas has the res, src, assets folders?

Comment: You do realize you can get a screenshot from your device in DDMS right? ...

Comment: @user2547460 have u tried the XML that i have posted ..is there any issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this is what i have tried for you

My **Manifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testandroid"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testandroid.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/mainbg"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/headingmain" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginLeft="304dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/headingby" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/MainMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/playbutton" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:src="@drawable/playbutton" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/playbutton" />

    <!-- end of main menu! -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How did you cut out the background?

Comment: i hope there will be some designers in u r company they have a tools they will do that is it fine now or not

Comment: does it cause the problem? the problem that it pushes off the menu?

Comment: It works on my sony x8 but not in the emulator! it says "stopped unexpectedly.." what's wrong?

Comment: see i will suggest u first to remove all the minus values ...i checking it mean while u remove all the minus values

Comment: is it a problem if my package name is long 6 words?

Comment: it's working fine on my emulator as well as i have checked this on tablet ,and samsung ,micromax and karbon mobiles it's working fine

Comment: what android version do you use??

Comment: 4.0 i am using and 4.2 on the tab

Comment: my dear brother every thing is perfect working for me i don't know why it's happening with you post the log or mail me

Comment: well, okay, but one question, how can I put space between the buttons?

Comment: i have updated my answer with my manifest file try it brother

Comment: I sent you the log cat! By the way! You are the most awesome guy in the world! Thank you so much bro!!!

Comment: how can I put space between the buttons?

Comment: i have updated XML see that change the margin top property as per u r requirement

Comment: Thanks it 's better, you are a great person but still not working on my emulator

Comment: ha ha ha now i am not getting what i can say u sorry brother

Comment: Thanks everything works, best guy in the world I recommend him to google for an android developer!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In this case a margin top on your menu LinearLayout will be an offset from the bottom of the 2nd image - You cannot assume to know the distance between the bottom of the 2nd image and the bottom of the screen, so don't try to lay things out like so. A negative weight will be ignored.

Also, it sounds like your menu bar is reproducing an iOS feature, please use the Android equivalent - http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html The ActionBar is available in the support libraries for older Android versions

Comment: But I don't have any menu bar, it's a fullscreen app, can you please tell me what I shoud do to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: If you're trying to put a 200dp menu bar into your layout, it can probably not be a full screen app?

Comment: the two images on the top are just logos, not menu bar, does it cause the problem that pushes off the menubar LinearLayout?